# firebase 3.0 on query

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a project where i want to extract a list from a query using firebase 3.0. I am quite new to this but I imagine that there is a simple answer to my question.

I have this structure :

```
requests : {
       luke1 : {
              1 : {
                    .../...
                     users : {
                              0 : {
                                   username : joseph,
                                   answered : 0
                                   }
                              1 : {
                                   username : mark,
                                   answered : 1
                                   }
                               }
                    }
                 }
             }
```

Basically the logged in user (luke1) sends a request to a number of users (joseph and mark) and lets say i'm logged in as user: joseph. 
I want to have get a list of requests sent to joseph which where not replied yet

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("requests/");
```

i want to know how can i write the query.

Thanks for taking time to read this and if you need more information from my end, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this kind of query you need to store in a variable the currentID of your user. After do this, just try something like the next query:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("request").child(currentUserId).child("users");
```

If I'm not wrong, it will return you the query that you want.

Answer (score 0):

When using Firebase (and in most NoSQL databases), you will often find that you end up modeling the data for the way your app wants to consume it.

So with you current data model, you can easily get the requests sent **by** a specific user.

```
ref.child("requests/luke1").on("child_added", ...
```

But you cannot yet easily find the requests sent **to** a specific user. To allow querying for that data easily, you could add an inverted data structure to your database:

```
received: {
    joseph: {
        0: {
            from: luke1
            answered: 0
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can easily get joseph's unanswered requests with:

```
ref.child("received/joseph").orderByChild("answered").equalTo(0).on("child_added", ...
```

Your initial response is likely that this sort of data duplication is bad. But it's actually quite common in NoSQL databases.

There are many more ways to model this structure. For a great introduction to the topic, I recommend this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).